# How to select and save value from column based on name in pandas?

Tags: excel, pandas, xml, dataframe, data-cleaning

I need help cleaning a hellish excel file. Essentially, I have the tabular output of a deeply nested .xml database (I don't have access to the original xml), meaning that final values that I want to work with are spread across multiple columns. The database also does not consistently output the same columns, so I need to make sure that my code is dynamic in allowing me to search columns that change from each output.

In short, I need to preferentially select certain values from a variety of columns. I almost always want the most-specific (or deeply nested xml) value of these. For example:

```
INPUT:
d = { 'level_1': ['mammal', 'mammal', 'mammal', 'mammal', 'mammal', 'shell', 'mammal', 'aves'], 'level_2': ['cattle', 'sheep/goat', 'sheep/goat', None, None, None, 'pig', None], 'level_3': [None, 'sheep', None, None, 'gazelle', None, None, None]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data= d)

print(df)

OUTPUT:  
  level_1     level_2  level_3
0  mammal      cattle     None
1  mammal  sheep/goat    sheep
2  mammal  sheep/goat     None
3  mammal        None     None
4  mammal        None  gazelle
5   shell        None     None
6  mammal         pig     None
7    aves        None     None
```

I want it to look like this:

```
       animal
0      cattle
1       sheep
2  sheep/goat
3      mammal
4     gazelle
5       shell
6         pig
7        aves
```

I've tried to conduct this search via .iterrows, using predefined search dictionaries, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

```
search_1 = ['pig', 'sheep', 'cattle', 'shell', 'aves', 'gazelle']

search_2 = ['sheep/goat']

search_3 = ['mammal']

column_names = list(df.columns.values) # I need to make this dynamic because the number and order of the columns shift between different spreadsheets

search_lists = [search_1, search_2, search_3]

tax_result_found = 0

tax_result_failed = 0

results_temp = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():

    sresult = None

    found_flag = 0

    for search_level in search_lists:
        if found_flag == 0:
            for search_term in search_level:
                if search_term in df.loc[column_names]:
                    found_flag = 1
                    sresult = search_level[search_term]
                    break


    if found_flag == 0:
        tax_result_failed += 1
        sresult = "FAILED_CLEANUP"
    else:
        tax_result_found += 1

    results_temp.append(sresult)



print()
fixed_df = pd.DataFrame(data = results_temp, columns = 'animal')
print(fixed_df)

print('Number of failed clean ups:', tax_result_failed)
print('Number of successful clean ups:', tax_result_found)
```

I get the following error: KeyError: "None of [Index(['level_1', 'level_2', 'level_3'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"

I'm relatively new to Python so I'm sure I've made some mistakes. What do I need to fix? Is there an easier way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

In your case do `ffill` and select the last one

```
df['animal'] = df.ffill(1).iloc[:,-1]
Out[785]: 
0        cattle
1         sheep
2    sheep/goat
3        mammal
4       gazelle
5         shell
6           pig
7          aves
Name: level_3, dtype: object
```

Comment: Ah, right. I hadn't thought about this because my original df has many columns in between these, but if I create a subset of what I need based on column names, then this *should* work. Thanks!!